# Ubuntu 14.04 SSD started freezing recently

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, ssd, radeon

So I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (3.13.0-77-generic) x64 with an Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB and up until a few weeks ago everything worked fine. Now I am getting random frequent freezes.  Especially when I am watching movies either on smplayer (mpv) or on the web (Chrome).

I have an AMD ATI Radeon HD 5770 with the Ubuntu generic driver.

I have this on dual boot with Windows 7 and a proprietary Samsung software where I checked my SSD health and it says everything is fine there.

What else can I do to fix this? Was this an Ubuntu update that broke this for me? Should I scan my SSD with another tool? Could it be my ATI?

UPDATE:

I think this might have been related to chrome after all.. after i `google-chrome --disable-gpu` i haven't had any freezing problems

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the freezes are SSD related?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might have been related to Google Chrome after all... After I ran `google-chrome --disable-gpu` I haven't had any freezing problems.